良いように使う meaning
Friend A: なにが恋人だよ　この関係はどう見ても家族だろ
Friend B: 良いように使うな~ そのセリフ
This exchange is between two friends. Friend B points to A their relationship is like "Lovers" but A resort they are more like family.
To which B replies it.  I'm not sure how to take 良いように使うな here? いいように使われる seems to be commonly used but I can't make sense of the non passive us here.

Did you notice that in the normal order it's そのセリフ（を）いいように使う?

Yes, I noticed the sentence was reverse

"but I can't make sense of the non passive [use] here" - did you try just considering it as the sum of its parts? 良い describes a よう, which is the に of Friend A's (そのセリフを)使う. Seems pretty straightforward. But you tagged the question "imperatives", which makes me think you've misunderstood the な. That isn't the plain form + な imperative; it's just a sentence-ending な (dialectical variant of ね). Is that enough to clear it up?

The literal translation is "You're using that line conveniently".
Here, Friend B is pointing out that A is opportunistically using that classic "we're like a family" excuse. This is known as a cliched tactic used to deflect or deny romantic implications.
